# Converting values in a dictionary to integers - python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is created by reading in keys and values from a csv file. The csv file looks like this:

```
Alice, 8
Tom, 10
Ben, 8
Ben, 9
Alice, 10
Tom, 8
```

This is read into an empty dictionary called scores:

```
scores={}
file = open("file.csv","r")
for line in csv.reader(file):
    scores.setdefault(line[0], []).append(line[1])
```

This creates a dictionary that looks like this:

```
scores = {'Tom': ['10', '8'], 'Ben': ['8', '9'], 'Alice': ['8', '10']}
```

How can I append the values to this dictionary as integers so the dictionary would look like this:

```
scores = {'Tom': [10, 8], 'Ben': [8, 9], 'Alice': [8, 10]}
```

Comment: Just use `int()` to convert your `line[1]`. BTW, I recommend you to use `with open(filename) as file:` instead of `open()` since the latter requires manual `close()`

Comment: `scores = collections.defaultdict(list)` will avoid the need for setdefault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `int()` conversion.

```
scores.setdefault(line[0], []).append(int(line[1]))
```

By the way, you could use a neat Python feature to extract the lines to named variables, like so:

```
for name, age in csv.reader(file):
    scores.setdefault(name, []).append(age)
```